# What info are exposed inside the site activity modern web part? can i know what other users viewed?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365, modern-experience, modern-pages

I have added a "Site Activity" web part inside our modern team site. and to check what this web part expose >> i login using 2 different users (UserA & UserB).

UserA. will see what he/she have viewed and what others have edited.

UserB. will see what he/she have viewed and what others have edited.

so can i conclude that the site activity web part will never expose what other users have viewed? and will only expose this view info to the same user ? or this is not always the case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This web part automatically shows recent activity on your site, such as files uploaded, edits made, lists and libraries created, and so on.

Currently, we can only configure how many items to show at a time, there is not a  setting to configure users.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the info, but my question is about if this web part will expose what other users have viewed? or will only show what the current users view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your conclusion is correct.
This is the behavior I have noticed as well.
There isn't much information in the documentation for this webpart, but it makes sense not to display stuff viewed by other users as that data can become unmanageable very quickly even with a few users.